# How to convert .c file to .so file in Linux? I have .c file. & need Linux command to convert this to .so file

Tags: linux, putty

I got mod_ldap.c & mod_authnz_ldap.c file. I need mod_ldap.so & mod_authnz_ldap.so file using Linux command.

Comment: Header file is missing from your directory check all the header file is there or not

Answer (score 0):

its two step method to create so file from your c or cpp file

first things you need to create object file  from c file

second things you need to create so file from object file

step by step process to generate so file

*step to create object file from c file*

1) **gcc -c -fPIC mod_ldap.c mod_ldap.o**

**gcc -c -fPIC mod_authnz_ldap.c mod_authnz_ldap.o**

*step to create so file from object file*

2) **gcc mod_ldap.o -shared -o mod_ldap.so**

**gcc mod_authnz_ldap.o -shared -o mod_authnz_ldap.so**

Comment: I have already used these commands. But below error is coming.gcc: mod_authnz_ldap.o: No such file or directory
mod_authnz_ldap.c:17:25: error: ap_provider.h: No such file or directory
mod_authnz_ldap.c:18:19: error: httpd.h: No such file or directory
mod_authnz_ldap.c:19:25: error: http_config.h: No such file or directory

Comment: post your code in GitHub and share the link,i think there is some problem in your header file or in code

Comment: I am very new in this. I have no idea about the header file. I have only the .c file. I am running this file in server using gcc -c -fPIC mod_authnz_ldap.c mod_authnz_ldap.o command. I am using this block of code.https://github.com/schakko/global-bind-user-for-mod_auth_ldap/blob/master/src/mod_authnz_ldap.c

Comment: without header file you cannot create object file,include all the header file and it seem your code is same as what Apache using for tomcat server